# Loop not completing

Tags: c#

I have a simple program that is used to pass inputs to an array given the inputted size and inputted elements by the user as follows:
[Full code](http://pastebin.com/XP3mmmq0)

All the code works fine except this snippet :

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            flagger = false;
                while(flagger == false) {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Please enter number " + i + " : ");
                nextInput = System.Console.ReadLine();
                flagger = errorCheck(nextInput);
            }

            int varPass = System.Convert.ToInt32(nextInput);
            System.Console.WriteLine(flagger);
            arr[i] = varPass;
        }
```

No matter what size I input the loop exits early and sorts an array with some empty elements, can anyone see the problem?

Comment: The only way it can complete before `i` reaches `size` is by throwing an exception.

Comment: Problem is with inner `while` loop. It seems that method `errorCheck` never returns `true`. By the way, `flagger == false` is the same as `!flagger`.

Comment: Hi, why is this? I thought my logic was correct

Comment: When I run the program on my system errorCheck returns true when an integer value is inputted

Comment: @MattMcGrath Update question with code of `errorCheck` method, so we can see issue better.

Comment: Wrap your method in a try/catch

Comment: Code is provided in the link to past bin under "Full code" in the question

Comment: changing the static `size` to `arr.length` will solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In errorCheck you're setting the value of size as you're passing it in the out parameter.

So the next time the user inputs a number smaller than i the loop exits early.
Create a dummy int or handle your error checking differently.
Example:

```
static bool errorCheck(string input) {  
    int temp=0;
    if (int.TryParse(input, out temp))  
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

This "bug" happens because size is static.

You can simplify your code further by just returning the result of TryParse.

```
static bool checkErr(string input) {
    int temp=0;
    return int.TryParse(input, out temp);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this revelation. How can I alter the code so that I just check if input is an int and then continue?

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the link +1

Comment: @Steve I do wish I had a crystal ball though :(

Comment: not really , why 5 upvotes? the problem was much simpler... replace `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)` with `for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)`

Comment: @mehow While we're at it, move everything to a Class so we don't accidentally pass static parameters and other issues as well. While it's correct to use a parameter in the loop instead of arr.Length, it's definitely not correct to arbitrarily pass a parameter to TryParse. Why the hate on upvotes?

Comment: its just how you see the problem. i see it differently because his CheckErr method is working fine to me.

Comment: This is beyond my interpretation of the problem, if i was writing this code I would definitely use arr.Length in my loop, but I would never pass an arbitrary parameter that could get reused. (Don't forget we are seeing part of the program, maybe the size parameter is needed later where the array has changed/discarded) to each his own, but you're promoting buggy code.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included errorCheck method which seems crucial to me.
If errorCheck returns true the Loop **WILL** end prematurely.
EDIT: Oops, you did include a link to full code.

As my predecessor said, errorCheck(...) modifies "size". Maybe that's why I still prefix member variables with underscore. It's so easy to miss.